Why are slices dynamically sized?
In the tutorial it explains &str is a slice reference to str. str is the slice. And we can create a slice like this:
let string: &str = "a string";
let arr: [i32; 4] = [1, 2, 3, 4];
let arr_slice: &[i32] = &arr[..2];

Here, I think, the size of slice is quite clear. arr_slice has a reference to two i32 elements. If I understand it, the equivalent in C would look like:
typedef struct {
    void* ptr;
    int length;
} slice;

The length can be known through the slice syntax [...]. Thus, size of slice can also be inferred by sizeof(type of ptr) * length which behaves like array. So that in the example above, it's very easy to know the size of slice itself at compile time.
Why does Rust make slice a DST?

The compile time equivalent to a slice is an array, and they are not always easy to work with, they can't even express every possible algorithm.

Otherwise, you'd need a new function/struct for every slice of different size. Also, then you wouldn't be able to take a slice from a runtime value, like from a user input or some other computed value.

arr_slice is not a slice, but a reference to a slice. You cannot refer to a DST except via some indirection (such as a reference), and the indirection itself is statically sized. And a reference to a DST is a fat pointer and is where the additional data, such as the length of a slice, is stored. (It wouldn't be possible for a slice to store its own length adjacently, or else you'd have nowhere to put the length of a sub-slice; hence the length goes with the reference.)

In short, because that's what they are designed to be, a sequence of items of dynamic length. There is an inherent need to handle variable-length sequences for many programs.
The code you show doesn't need to use a dynamic slice, for it, in theory slicing could work like this:
let arr_slice: &[i32; 2] = &arr[..2];

But that now means the index has to be known at compile time, you can't use user input to get a subset. The following code:
let length = rand::Rng::gen_range(&mut rand::thread_rng(), 0..=arr.len());
let arr_slice = &arr[..length];

is no longer possible because you can't know the runtime value length at compile time.

It would also mean every function accepting a slice would need to be generic on the slice size, rather than a single copy of the function being able to accept slices of varying size. That's a heck of a lot of code bloat if each unique slice size creates a unique compiled copy of the function in question.

It seems like that this is designed for dynamic sized array? But how about string? In my understanding, string literal is  stored as a kind of static data. Especially for the immutable string variable. Then why do we have to use &str ?

@ucag: For the exact same reason you use slices? Do you want every function that works with strings to either: 1) Only accept String (taking ownership of a complete, dynamically allocated string), or 2) Be generic on the compile-time size of the str it's receiving (so it is separately compiled for length 0, length 1, length 2, etc. strings)? The string literals are also &str, because that means they can refer to the string data in read-only memory in the binary, rather than needing to dynamically allocate a String.

You're correct it's stored as 'static lifetime data. But to use it with code that handles arbitrary text, it needs to: 1) Not pass it around as owned data (you're not the unique owner of shared singleton data that can't be cleaned up) and 2) Be compatible with APIs that accept text from other sources (e.g. a view of a portion of an existing String, not just string literals). Sure, you could introduce a third string-like type for string literals, and require them to be handled separately via generics that would know their exactly length. But that's a lot of complexity for little gain.

In this imaginary world, I inadvertently indicated that option #1 for functions that work with strings would only accept String by value; it could accept &String/&mut String to avoid taking ownership, but the only "benefit" that would have over &str is that it would include the dynamic size of the string in the String object itself, rather than smuggling it in a wide-pointer. But that's something you can do already if you want to, it has no perf benefit, and it means basically all string operations would have to make new Strings, rather than views into existing strings.

@ShadowRanger @ShadowRanger Thanks for ur patient and detailed answer. What you mentioned is reasonable. But for string, I do not think it's necessary. For all string, they are just arrays. For slice itself, I just simply take it as a kind of data structure which keeps the start ptr and length. When comes with code like arr[1..2], we can just simple allocate a fixed size of struct to store these two piece of information.

@ShadowRanger As explained in the Rust doc, slice is just view of sequential data. We do not need to re-create or copy the original data in the heap. Thus, for slice, except for dynamic created array, the size of it can be determined at compile time. Size of slice itself is fixed somehow.  I still can not understand data structure like this simple will be designed to be allocated at runtime. For the example of slice as the function parameter, if I do it in C, I would just pass the pointer of the created slice and its size to the function.

What's more, because of the DST feature of slice, the only way to use is by reference &. In my poor rust experience, the one who creates the variable owns it. So, the compiler owns slice? And if expand this idea more, the compiler owns all DST??

"the only way to use is by reference" not true, you can have Box<[u8]>, Rc<[u8]>, Arc<str>, …

@cafce25 ha, I do not learn that far. I'll have a look at it.

What advantage to you hope to get from string slices being of statically known length? String handling is mostly used in IO, and that is a very dynamic field by nature, hence the natural representation is dynamic. str isn't statically sized and doesn't have a statically sized equivalent because it lacks uses.

@ucag: &arr[1..2] is a "fixed size of struct storing two pieces of information", the pointer to the raw data and the number of elements. And your point about views is what I've been telling you all this time (by explaining how annoying and wasteful a design that didn't separate String from str, with string literals being str, would be). String literals are views of program static data. They're non-owning, so they can't be String. Your "if I do it in C" point is exactly what the wide-pointers are doing, Rust simplifies by passing one value that encodes the pointer and size.

I have no idea what you're trying to say about ownership here, at all. str (and all slices) are explicitly non-owning, they're views of data they don't own. They can be views of static program data (as with string literals), or views of the contents of a String object, or a view of a [u8] created by std::str::from_utf8 (where the view of [u8] is itself non-owning), or a view of a raw pointer to u8 and a length that provide to std::str::from_raw_parts that you promise is really valid UTF-8 data. The static program data has a compile-time known length, but the rest doesn't.

@ShadowRanger str would be owning the data if it could exist on it's own (else Box<str> wouldn't own any data either, but it does). &str is not owning because it's a reference.

Thanks all friends for helping me understanding the question as well as discussion under the post. Now I want to summary all known information to a complete and logical answer.
I want to take the typical slice usage as an example. let's talk about str and &str.
First, we should understand size of what kind of data type can be known at compile time. size means we know (the compiler knows) how many bytes to use for the data. compile time means we can know the information without running the program. size of data type i32 is known at compile time, which is 4 bytes. That is to say, when come with code like let i:i32 = 1;, the compiler knows it needs 4 bytes for variable i. However, str is a data type in Rust, which is designed to represent string in any length. Thus, when compiler sees code like let string:str = "a string";, it can only knows a str variable declared but can not understand how many bytes need to allocate for this variable then the compilation will fail.
Here is the problem to programmers who's new to Rust (at least to me). Size of the literal a string is quite obvious, which is 8 bytes. Why does not the compiler know its size? After the discussion under this question and more searching, I want to try to explain this.
Now please think of code below to figure out how many bytes for each variable
let int:i32;
let f:f32;
let string:str;

We can easily see that variable int takes 4 bytes in memory as well as f. But how about string? it is impossible to know size of it until it is being assigned like string = "a string"; so that we can know string takes 8 bytes. Thus, size of string can only be determined when it is being assigned. Here is the dynamic part.
As it is known to all, string literal is stored as static data in the program, which means that "a string" will be encoded into the final binary and will be loaded into memory when the program launches. And it will not be loaded into heap or stack frame when you not use it. It is stored at the static data section somewhere else of memory. When a function starts to run, the compiler needs information to allocate memory for this function, which is known as stack frame. If a i32 variable declared in a function, the compiler knows it needs 4 byte on stack for this variable. How about str?  We only can infer the size after the data loaded.
Thus, size of str can not be understood at compile time. But we do need a string in code. If we think this in C, it will be easy
char* string;

Just simply declare string as the char pointer. Pointer has fixed size. Rust do this in a similar way.
let string:&str;

Use a str reference. The pointer of str is a little bit different from traditional pointer. It's a fat pointer. fat pointer is basically a pointer twice size than normal pointer. Why fat pointer? If we want to use string variable in c to a function, we have to tell the function size of string, signature like void function(char* string, size_t string_size). In Rust, fat pointer contains the length of underneath literal string data. And the length information is compiled when compiler comes with an assignment.
// print size of fat pointer

dbg!(size_of::<&u32>()); // 8
dbg!(size_of::<&[u32]>()); // 16

Thus we can do this in Rust by &str
let mut string:&str;
string = "a string";
println!("{}", string);
string = "another string";
println!("{}",string);

We know string is just an array of char, which can be similarly understand like this (code below is just for illustrating, there will be a compile error if really run it, because type of s1 and s2 is a sized array)
let s1 = ['a',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g'];
let s2 = ['a','n','o','t','h','e','r',' ','s','t','r','i','n','g'];

Now we can use fat pointer to stands for both of s1 and s2 thus we
(code below is just for illustrating, there will be a compile error if really run it, because type of s1 and s2 is a sized array)
let mut string:&str;
string = s1;
string = s2;

As we can see, it's very easy for us to generalize this idea. Slice does not have to have a fixed size. We can use slice reference to visit data in any length.
let arr = [1,2,3,4];
let arr_view = &arr[1..];
// or
let n:i32;
// get n value from somewhere else
let arr_view = &arr[1..n];

And slice does not care about the data source. Data source can come from static data section in memory or from heap or stack.

"We know string is just an array of char" it's actually not, it's utf-8 encoded. Which means a variable number of bytes reprpesents each char.

ur right, they are bytes.
